# Где по чистой архитектуре нужно резолвить строки в мультиязычных приложениях

Tags: java, android, архитектура

У меня приложение на двух языках. В данный момент архитектура отсутсвует и обычную модельку

```
public class MailBoxModel {
    private final String name;
    private final int img;
    private final MailBoxType mailBox;

    public MailBoxModel(String name, int img, MailBoxType mailBox) {
        this.name = name;
        this.img = img;
        this.mailBox = mailBox;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public MailBoxType getMailBoxType() {
        return mailBox;
    }
}
```

которая используется в адаптере для подгрузки в `RecyclerView`, инициализируют прям во фрагменте вот так

```
new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.my_office_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_collabio, ProviderConstants.MAIN_BRAND_MAIL);
```

Я пытаюсь перейти на чистую архитектуру и вынес заполнение адаптера в презентер при связывании презентере с фрагментом

```
public class NewMailBoxModelProvider {
//TODO  временное решение надо продумать где хранить или как без контекста
    private Context context;

    public NewMailBoxModelProvider(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Collection<MailBoxModel> getMailBoxCollection(){
        return getOtherServices();
    }

    private List<MailBoxModel> getOtherServices() {
        List<MailBoxModel> result = new LinkedList<>();
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.my_office_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_collabio, ProviderConstants.MAIN_BRAND_MAIL));
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.outlook_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_outlook, MailBoxType.OUTLOOK));
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.google_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_google, MailBoxType.GMAIL));
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.mail_ru_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_mail_ru, MailBoxType.MAIL_RU));
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.yandex_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_yandex, MailBoxType.YANDEX));
        //result.add(new MailBoxModel(getString(R.string.yahoo_box), R.drawable.banner_mail_yahoo, MailBoxType.YAHOO));
        result.add(new MailBoxModel(context.getString(R.string.other_mailbox), -1, MailBoxType.OTHER));
        return result;
    }

}
```

метод презентера

```
public void onCreate(){
        unsubscribeOnUnbindView(

                itemChose.subscribe(this::itemChoose),

                backBtnClicks.subscribe(avoid -> onBackCommandClick())
        );

        mailBoxes.call(newMailBoxModelProvider.getMailBoxCollection());
    }
```

вопрос как мне избавится от контекста в модельке? Можно поменять `String name` на `int name` а потом тогда резолвить `int` в `String` через `context.getString()`, но не могу понять где это делать, ведь презентер тоже не должен знать о контексте (желательно)

Comment: Зачем в модельке текст из ресурсов?

Comment: @Miha_x64 Она используется для подгрузки в адаптер списка, и на данный момент статична, то есть это тупо список из нескольких почтовых ящиков, которые красиво отображаются на экране (название, логотип). Может это вообще не стоит хранить в модельке, а где тогда? ведь это же бизнес, отобразить пять, а не шесть ящиков, а так же когда отобразить и тд.

Comment: Весь текст из ресурсов относится к представлению и должен использоваться во View, Адаптере и т. п., мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

В твоем кейсе можно сразу в **onCreate** твоего вью инициализировать лист, т.к. вся инфа статичная(любое изменение = залезть в исходник и редактировать руками). Если же хочется гибкости (фундамент под сценарий с альтернативным динамичным источником типа сервера) то придется адаптироваться под два варианта:

- *R.string.blabla*
- *String s = "blabla"*

Аналогично с другими ресурсами типа картинок(id\url).

Как вариант сделать в адаптере 2 модели с разными viewType, если речь про RecyclerView или более грязный вариант для ListView с толстой моделькой в которой будут оба варинта полей + if проверки например:

```
if(textResId = -1) {
   // use String вариант
} 
// else use ResId вариант
```

или

```
if(text = null) {
   // use ResId вариант
} 
// else use String вариант
```